# How to recover from deleted kernel on Solaris 2.6

Tags: solaris, boot

I suspect that I have delected the kernel in my Solaris 2.6 workstation.  I may have deleted /kernel by accident.  Now on bootup I get the error "misc/krtld not found".  I have the Solaris 2.6 installation disks.  Is it possible to re-install without a reformat?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, 2.6 -- that brings back memories.

Comment: When I cycle power, after the error message I get a prompt that says Enter Filename [/platform/SUNW,SPARCstation-5/kernel/unix]:.  It does this even when I boot with the install disc.  Not sure if the install disc is bootable.  I guess I have bricked my machine *cry*

Comment: What kind of machine is it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you powercycle, hit Stop-A (repeatedly, and quickly) (or send breaks if you're on a serial console) and you'll probably catch it before it starts looking at the disk and end up in the OBP where you should be able to boot off the CD... The 2.6 Install CD is probably bootable, but I admit I haven't seen one of those in a very long time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I hit stop-a and I got the bootprom prompt.  Then I entered boot cdrom.  Then I selected the upgrade option, since I am a little scared that the initial option will delete things I don't want deleted.  This is all running on a SPARCstation 5 that belongs in a museum.  Hopefully it will be done before tomorrow morning.

Comment: Success!  The upgrade option took about two hours on my Sparc 5.  Then the workstation booted normally, and all of my settings and software were the same as before!  I think my mistake was accidentally deleting /kernel.  This directory does not exist on Linux as far as I know, but on Solaris it holds, duh, the kernel.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Solaris, but many other OS's (OS X and other linux) come with boot CD's and not much is "tuned" in the kernel(some drivers if you installed extra things right into the kernel)

soooo... If you can, I would boot from a USB recovery distro (so you have full read/write access to the system in the easiest manner), put in the solaris disks, and copy what is necessary.

The worst that happens is you are forced to nuke/reinstall anyway.  But I have had luck with the above methods.

Comment: I think I would be in good shape if I could boot from cdrom and just copy over the /kernel and /platform directories.  My problem is I can't figure out how to boot from the cdrom.  I can't even get the bootprom prompt (ok>), all I get is the Enter Filename prompt.